# How can i make my html page to be fit in the pdf using Flying Saucer

Tags: java, flying-saucer

I am using `Flying Saucer` to convert XHTML page to PDF.

My XHTML page width is little longer. When I create the PDF, 10% right portion of the XHTML file is missing in PDF. How can i make my XHTML page to be fit in the PDF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`@page`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/) rule. please take a look at following FS documentation:

- [How do you control page size?](http://flyingsaucerproject.github.io/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html#xil_34)
- [How do you control page size on PDF output?](http://flyingsaucerproject.github.io/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html#xil_35)
- [How do you control page margins on PDF output?](http://flyingsaucerproject.github.io/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html#xil_36)