# Creating PDF File from dynamic invoice and XSLT

Tags: java, pdf, itext, apache-fop, flying-saucer

I have been trying to generate PDF files for customer invoices for a long time. Invoices are saved as xml files. And customers can have their own xslt file in order to have their own invoice view( if not default one is used as xslt ).

My Problem is transforming XML/ (X)HTML files to pdf files. I have read almost about all libraries for doing this and tried to transform almost with all of them.

1) Apache FOP

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071749/java-app-dev/convert-html-content-to-pdf-format.html

I transformed invoice xml to xhtml using default xslt and jtidy. And then I tried to convert generated xhtml to pdf with XSL-FO given by Antenna House.I managed to generate a pdf file with just header. also no success. Code for doing this below.

```
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Source xslt = new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/xslts/general.xslt"));
//      xslt.setSystemId("/xslts/general.xslt");
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);

        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);
        transformer.transform(domSource, result);
        String strResult = writer.toString();


        Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
//        tidy.setDropEmptyParas(true);
//        tidy.setJoinStyles(true);
        tidy.setInputEncoding("UTF-8");
        tidy.setOutputEncoding("UTF-8");
        tidy.setXHTML(true);
        tidy.setMakeClean(true);
        tidy.setForceOutput(true);

        ByteArrayInputStream boas = new ByteArrayInputStream(strResult.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        FileOutputStream baoOut = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\xxx\\out.pdf"));

        Document tiedDoc = tidy.parseDOM(boas, bos);

        DOMSource tiedDocDomSource = new DOMSource(tiedDoc);
        StringWriter writer2 = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result2 = new StreamResult(writer2);
        Transformer xsl2foTrans = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/xslt/xhtml2fo.xsl")));

        xsl2foTrans.transform(tiedDocDomSource, result2);


//        // ab hier

        final FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File(".").toURI());
        File userConfig = new File("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\pdfWork\\fop.xconf");
        FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
        // configure foUserAgent as desired

        // Setup output stream.  Note: Using BufferedOutputStream
        // for performance reasons (helpful with FileOutputStreams).
        OutputStream out = baoOut;
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(out);

        // Construct fop with desired output format
        Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, out);

        // Setup JAXP using identity transformer
        transformer = factory.newTransformer(); // identity transformer

        // Setup input stream
        Source src = new StreamSource(new StringReader(writer2.toString()));

        // Resulting SAX events (the generated FO) must be piped through to FOP
        Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

        // Start XSLT transformation and FOP processing
        transformer.transform(src, res);
        out.close();
```

2) IText

as far as i know, we should provide a valid xhtml to IText for generating PDF Files. so i transform invoice xml to html using default.xslt and then to xhtml using jtidy with setXhtml option true. i managed to generate pdf file  from given xhtml. But pdf is not rendered well.  somehow, css in style tag are not recognized. no success. code for doing this below

```
    StreamSource xslt = new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/xslt/general.xslt"));
//        StreamSource xslt =  new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\XXX\\Desktop\\pdfWork\\firm.xslt")));


        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
//      Source xslt = new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/xslts/general.xslt"));
//      xslt.setSystemId("/xslts/general.xslt");
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);

        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);
        transformer.transform(domSource, result);
        String strResult = writer.toString();


        Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
//        tidy.setDropEmptyParas(true);
        tidy.setJoinStyles(true);
        tidy.setInputEncoding("UTF-8");
        tidy.setOutputEncoding("UTF-8");
        tidy.setXHTML(true);
        tidy.setMakeClean(true);
        tidy.setForceOutput(true);

        ByteArrayInputStream boas = new ByteArrayInputStream(strResult.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        FileOutputStream baoOut = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\XXX\\Desktop\\pdfWork\\out.pdf"));

        tidy.parseDOM(boas, bos);


        com.itextpdf.text.Document documentText = new com.itextpdf.text.Document(PageSize.LETTER); // PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F, 0.0F
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(documentText, new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Onur\\Desktop\\pdfWork\\out.pdf")));
        documentText.open();

//        documentText.open();
//        HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(documentText);
//        htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(IOUtils.toString(new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray()), "UTF-8")));
//        documentText.close();

        XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
        worker.parseXHtml(pdfWriter, documentText, new StringReader(IOUtils.toString(new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray()))));
        documentText.close();
```

3) Flying Saucer

I did almost same steps as IText. I managed to generate PDF with recognized css style tag. single problem i have is table and some elements overflow. they are not fitting to the page. i solved this problem with page rule as suggested on

[How can i make my html page to be fit in the pdf using Flying Saucer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066964/how-can-i-make-my-html-page-to-be-fit-in-the-pdf-using-flying-saucer)

```
Document document = // invoice as document
    StreamSource xslt = new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/xslt/general.xslt"));

        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
//      Source xslt = new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/xslts/general.xslt"));
//      xslt.setSystemId("/xslts/general.xslt");
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);

        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);
        transformer.transform(domSource, result);
        String strResult = writer.toString();


        Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
        tidy.setInputEncoding("UTF-8");
        tidy.setOutputEncoding("UTF-8");
        tidy.setXHTML(true);
        tidy.setMakeClean(true);
        tidy.setForceOutput(true);

        ByteArrayInputStream boas = new ByteArrayInputStream(strResult.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        FileOutputStream baoOut = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\XXX\\Desktop\\pdfWork\\out2.pdf"));

        tidy.parseDOM(boas, bos);
        System.out.println(bos.toString("UTF-8"));


        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("/unicode/ARIALUNI.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

//        renderer.setDocument();
        renderer.setDocumentFromString(IOUtils.toString(new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray())));
//                renderer.setPDFVersion('');
        renderer.layout();
        renderer.createPDF(baoOut);
        renderer.finishPDF();
        baoOut.flush();
        baoOut.close();
```

as i said, i managed to generate PDF file from xhtml using flying saucer. But i had to add page rule and some inline styling in general.xslt for doing this. But problem is that each customer can have his own xslt for invoice view. so i dont want to touch and change xslt. general.xslt can be downloaded from link below. How can i achieve this ? is it possible ? Or what i am doing wrong ? Thanks in Advance!

http://www.efatura.gov.tr/dosyalar/kilavuzlar/UBL-TR1.2_Paketi.zip

Comment: As an alternative, you could convert xhtml to docx, so the user can edit the invoice if they wish and/or convert it to PDF if that is what they want to do.

Comment: thanks for your quickly reply @JasonPlutext. But  invoice is already sent and invoice is no more editable. Customer can download single invoice as pdf, several pdfs as zipped file or as merged as single pdf. i did all of them. My problem is that  content is not fitting to the page. And in order to solve it , i had to add page and some rules. But how can i achieve this without touching xslt and style inside xslt ? or do you have any recommends for any library for xml/html to pdf ?

Comment: If you want to create invoices, why don't you read the book [ZUGFeRD: The Future of Invoicing](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ZUGFeRD.html). You can also read it online [here](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/zugferd-future-invoicing) and whoever succeeds in reading the whole book up until [Chapter 7](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/zugferd-future-invoicing/7-creating-pdf-invoices-comfort), will discover that it's perfectly possible to create [invoices as HTML+CSS](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/zugferd-future-invoicing/6-creating-html-invoices) and convert them to nice PDFs.

Comment: You claim that iText doesn't take the CSS into account when converting the HTML to PDF. I have examples that show that iText can convert [HTML+CSS](http://developers.itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/C6F2.png) to [PDF](http://developers.itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/C7F1.png). Click on the links to see the screen shots of the results. You should try [the examples](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/zugferd-itext5).

Comment: Thank you for your reply and advice @BrunoLowagie. the Book is really interesting and also documentation is great. But it doesnt fit our requirements. i dont claim that iText generally doesn't take CSS into Account. IText is a great library used by many companies and other libraries as flying saucer etc. But it didnt work for my case. i also tried the same on http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/. unfortunately same result. :( .